# How to tell `keyof MyClass.prototype` in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I can define generic and force that in `genericForObj` passing only properties of a particular object.

```ts
class MyClass
{
  one(){};
  two(){};
}

function genericForObj<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: K)
{

}

const obj = new MyClass;

genericForObj(obj, 'one'); // OK

genericForObj(MyClass, 'one');
// Error: Argument of type '"one"' is not
// assignable to parameter of type '"prototype"'.
```

How to tell `keyof MyClass.prototype` in generic function?

Comment: `MyClass` has no static variable `one`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: As I write in my question, I want to check keys of `MyClass.prototype`

Comment: Why? Your class doesn't have `one` or `two` in its prototype, those are instance members, the class doesn't have them

Comment: No, the class have them in prototype and I want check this list of properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@gcnew](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13718), the following `genericForClass` does exactly what I wanted:

```ts
class MyClass
{
  one(c: boolean){};
  two(){};
}

function genericForClass
<T extends Function, K extends keyof T['prototype']>
(classHandler: T, method: K)
{

}

genericForClass(MyClass, 'one') // OK
genericForClass(MyClass, 'fake') // Error
```

Answer (score 0):

This class:

```
class MyClass {
    one: 1;
    two: 2;
}
```

Compiles into:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

As you can see, the prototype isn't changed, and `one` and `two` aren't even present in the compiled js.
If you assign a value to them (instead of declaring the types):

```
class MyClass {
    one = 1;
    two = 2;
}
```

The it compiles to:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.one = 1;
        this.two = 2;
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

Again, nothing is added to the prototype, the members are assigned to the instance (`this`).

Because of that you can not get `one` or `two` as `keyof A`.

Comment: Just try in my example of code write `genericForObj(MyClass.prototype, 'one');`. P.S. TypeScript can to compile your code to class `tsc --target es2015 your.ts`.

Comment: Just try to place `console.log(obj[prop]);` in the body of the `genericForObj` function and you'll see that you get `undefined` because of what I wrote in my answer

Comment: Even with `es6` classes the members are only present in the instance and not in the class.

Comment: But if you do `const newObj = new obj; obj[prop]` in the body of the `genericForObj` all works as expected.

Comment: That's right, because then `obj` is an instance and it has those members (they are assigned in the constructor). But the class doesn't have those members.

Comment: OK, I change properties to methods. What you think now?

Comment: In this case you need to use `genericForObj(MyClass.prototype, "one")`. `MyClass` and `MyClass.prototype` are different, both in value and type, you can't use one as the other. `MyClass["one"]` is `undefined`, while `MyClass.prototype["one"]` is `function () { }`.

Answer (score 0):

the code below returns all properties and methods of a class:

```
keyof typeof MyClass['prototype']
```